# Flask-Login current_user changing to the most recent User class query result

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, abc

My implementation of Flask-Login is working well across my site, with the exception of contexts where I need to make additional queries on the `User` class. For example, when I try to generate a list of `User` instances representing other users with whom the `current_user` shares a task, the values stored in `current_user` are rewritten each time a new instance of `User` is created. In addition, the attributes of each of the other previously-generated `User` instances are also overwritten, with the exception of the `User.id` attribute, which remains unique (and correct).

I am using pyAirtable as an ORM between Flask and an Airtable base containing user data. The ORM is experimental and built using [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). I wonder whether this issue may be due to a conflict between [instance and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804341/creating-new-object-instance-but-old-instance-was-changed-in-python).

I specifically suspect the `_fields` variable may be the culprit, because it appears as both a class variable and an instance variable in the [source for the base `Model`](https://pyairtable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyairtable/orm/model.html#Model). (The issue may also be with the `from_id()` method, which I use in a list comprehension to generate the aforementioned list of `User` instances from a list of Airtable record IDs.) However, I'm not experienced enough with ABCs or Python to be able to determine this for sure. I've tried fiddling with the `pyairtable` package for debugging, to no avail.

What am I missing? Is this an issue with `pyairtable`, `flask-login`, an unexpected interaction between the two packages, or just my implementation?